# In AWS, how to set the ec2-user password of a linux vm?

Tags: passwords, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-web-services

I have created a RHEL VM in AWS. I can SSH to it with my private key. After the SSH connection, when I try to set a password to my default "ec2-user" it is asking me for a password? But I don't know it.

Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to setup a password? (generally not a great idea) Have you tried running `passwd ec2-user` as root?

Comment: I don't have the root password neither.

Comment: Did you try using `sudo`?

Comment: With sudo, the system asks my ec2-user password that i don't have.